# How can I loop my AsyncTask to download a data blob in a loop?

Tags: android, download, background

I'm running `httpsCommand` (shown below, via `clientTask()` from *MainActivity*) and downloading about 1KB of data from a webserver. I plan to update a ListView in *MainActivity* (I think that's possible, but I recall it being a bit annoying last time I did it) with the downloaded data inside `myListAllDoneListener()`.  I'd like to run this in a loop every 5 minutes to check for new data.

I've tried running `new myCLientTask().execute()...` inside a while loop (using `Thread.sleep` and try/catch) but it only seemed to run one loop and crashed after 15 seconds or so. Found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059217/managing-background-download-android) but it's not quite answered. How can I background this data download?

```
// ** MainActivity.java **
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
   ...
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {    
    new clientTask(getApplicationContext(), myListAllDoneListener, ...);
        ...

   private AsyncTaskCompleteListener myListAllDoneListener = new AsyncTaskCompleteListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(ArrayList<String> data, String msg, int statuscode)
      {
        // update listview with new data
        ...


//** clientTask.java **
public class clientTask extends Activity
{ 
  ArrayList<String> mData;
  ...

  public clientTask (Context ctx, AsyncTaskCompleteListener ... String cmd, ...)
  {
    ...
    new myClientTask().execute();
    ...


  private class myClientTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
  {
  ...

  protected Object doInBackground (Object... params)
  {
     mData = httpsCommand (mCmd);
     ...
```

Comment: share crash error logcat ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Thread.sleep in activity. It will block your UI. To run a periodic task 
[Look this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay/6242292#6242292) using Handlers. 
Also, there are some things wrong with your code. You shouldn't create object of an Activity class and use it for such things.